# snap install of kotlin-native

Tags: software-installation, compiler, snap

I'm a former Java developer attempting to learn Kotlin. So far so good, but on attempting to install kotlin-native to compile to a platform other than the JVM:

```
sudo snap install kotlin-native
```

I get the following message.

```
error: snap "kotlin-native" not available as specified (see 'snap info kotlin-native')
```

This is different from what I would get for a gibberish name, i.e.,

```
error: snap "kotlin-native1231" not found
```

However, when I type in the suggested `snap info kotlin-native`, I get this.

```
error: no snap found for "kotlin-native"
```

Which is exactly what I would get for gibberish. This is what was recommended to me on the web, but much of the material dates from 2016 and it may be that kotlin-native is literally not available anymore; but does anyone know why I'm getting this behavior, and what may have happened to it? My fallback is to simply install it from the web directly, which is doable but not preferable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error: snap "kotlin-native" not available as specified` means that no package named kotlin-native (as specified) is available. A snap package named *kotlin* is available in the Snap Store, and this is a link to download
[kotlin-native-linux-1.3.72.tar.gz](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/download/v1.3.72/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.72.tar.gz) from GitHub.

Results of `snap info kotlin` :

Command line Kotlin compiler. Statically typed programming language for modern multiplatform applications.

Available tools:

- kotlinc
- kotlinc-jvm
- kotlinc-js
- kotlin-dce-js

Commands:

- kotlin
- kotlin.kotlin-dce-js
- kotlin.kotlinc
- kotlin.kotlinc-js
- kotlin.kotlinc-jvm

Installation:

```
sudo snap install kotlin
```

Example:

Create a file named hello.kt and enter the following contents:

```java
fun main() {
  println("Hello Kotlin!")
}
```

To compile and run the application execute the following commands:

```
kotlin.kotlinc hello.kt  
kotlin HelloKt
```

Results:

```
Hello Kotlin!
```

Comment: I don't suppose you know what happened to the previous kotlin-native then? Is it merged with another package?

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin I could simply say that the previous kotlin-native snap package is nowhere to be found and leave it at that, but it has been my experience that snap packages that have bugs were removed from the Snap Store following complaints made by many users. It has also been my experience that buggy snap packages like Opera were removed from the Snap Store because the application couldn't be launched and then restored back to the Snap Store when the bug was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration.